# method for optaining access token from an authorization server

Tags: ssl, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am reading this [Auth 2.0 Mutual-TLS Client Authentication and Certificate-Bound Access Tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-mtls-17#section-1.2)

The manual states that the client asks the auth server for an access token. However, the manual does not specify the way (HOW) that this happens. Is this happens during the mutual TLS procedure? or after that?

Comment: It just refers to the normal way OAuth 2.0 works, i.e. how is done is defined in the OAuth 2.0 standard. So please see there. And an access token is provided __after__ authentication, which also means after authentication using mutual TLS. Also, please don't link to the draft when there is already a RFC for this available.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: you mean here right? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3

Comment: Access token is all over this RFC not only in section 1.3.